# Use border padding in Fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Bumping into an issue trying to set the 'padding' parameter inside Fancybox.

```
padding  : '4, 4, 4, 4,',
```

Only sets the top and bottom padding.

```
padding  : '4px, 4px, 4px, 4px',
```

Doesn't work either. Using version 2.1.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs:

> Padding:
>   Integer, Array; Default value: 15
>   Space inside fancyBox around content. Can be set as array - [top, right, bottom, left].

Therefore you need to provide the values you want as an array:

```
padding : [4, 4, 4, 4],
```

Or, as all values are the same, you can supply a single integer:

```
padding: 4,
```

Comment: Thanks Roy. Wasn't doing the array syntax correctly!